# NHibernate - multiple JOIN to the same table by different keys

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Another NHibernate JOIN problem.

I'm trying to join two different properties from one table by different two
keys.
But I can't get the second JOIN property.

Simplified example -

My class -

```
namespace Domain
{
   public class Message
   {
      #region private Members

      private string _id;
      private string _senderID;
      private string _recipientID;
      private string _recipientName;
      private string _senderName;

      #endregion

      #region Public Properties

      public virtual string ID
      {
          get { return _id; }
          set { _id = value; }
      }

      public virtual string ID
      {
          get { return _id; }
          set { _id = value; }
      }

      public virtual string SenderID
      {
          get { return _senderID; }
          set { _senderID= value; }
      }

      public virtual string RecipientID
      {
          get { return _recipientID; }
          set { _recipientID= value; }
      }

      public virtual string SenderName
      {
          get { return _senderName; }
          set { _senderName= value; }
      }

      public virtual string RecipientName
      {
          get { return _recipientName; }
          set { _recipientName= value; }
      }

      #endregion

      #region Constructors

      public Message()
      {
          _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      }

      #endregion
  } 
}
```

Mapping -

```
 <class name="Domain.Message" table="Messages" >
    <id name="ID">
      <column name="OID"/>
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="SenderID" unique="true">
       <column name="SenderID" unique="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="RecipientID" unique="true">
       <column name="RecipientID" unique="true"/>
    </property>
    <join table="CompanyData"  optional="true" >
       <key column="CompanyID" property-ref="SenderID" />
       <property name="SenderName" column="CompanyName" unique="true" lazy="false"/>
    </join>
    <join table="CompanyData"  optional="true" >
       <key column="CompanyID" property-ref="RecipientID" />
       <property name="RecipientName" column="CompanyName" unique="true" lazy="false"/>
    </join>
 </class>
```

but I get the following SQL -

```
SELECT  this_.OID as OID30_0_, this_.SenderID as Sender30_0_,
this_.RecipientID as Recipient30_0_, this_1_.CompanyName as SiteID9_0_
FROM Messages this_
left outer join CompanyData this_1_ on
this_.SenderID=this_1_.CompanyID
left outer join CompanyData this_2_ on
this_.RecipientID=this_2_.CompanyID
```

And I want -

```
 SELECT  this_.OID as OID30_0_, this_.SenderID as Sender30_0_,
 this_.RecipientID as Recipient30_0_, this_1_.CompenyName as
 SiteID9_0_ , this_2_.CompanyName as SiteID10_0_
 FROM Messages this_
 left outer join CompanyData this_1_ on
 this_.SenderID=this_1_.CompanyID
 left outer join CompanyData this_2_ on
 this_.RecipientID=this_2_.CompanyID
```

I'm using NHibernate 3.2

Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the mapping. Can you post the class code as well?

Comment: What is RecipientName being populated with when you run this? The SenderName value? I'm inclined to think this may be a bug. nHibernate may be trying to optimize incorrectly for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the RecipientName is filled with the SenderName value. Is there anything I can do turn off the optimization?

Comment: Probably not. Though you are not completely out of luck. If this class is supposed to be read only you could easily create a view and have your mapping point to that instead. This would at least be a work around until you can get this issue noticed by the Hibernate team.

Comment: I will use the VIEW mapping option. But this solution might not be enough next time. Thank you!

Comment: Let me know when/if they reply. I'd like to know if this is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this cannot be done at the moment with NHibenate mappings.
The closest solution, suggested by [Spencer Ruport](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52551/spencer-ruport), is to create a view and map the object to it.

Answer (score 3):

I was lurking thru the internet all day long to find solution to same problem.
What I found is thread on [hibernate board](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-879). I took solution from [Ashkan Aryan](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-879#commentauthor_39793_verbose) . So if anyone else gets headaches about solution and don't want to use views I will post my code which I am using now.

I have to use from 1 to 12 joins on same table so creating views is to much confusing.

```
private void addParagraphsQuery(DetachedCriteria sourceQuery, List<ParagraphContentArgument> paragraphsArguments)
{
    DetachedCriteria dc;
    Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.Conjunction();
    string alias = string.Empty;

    if (paragraphsArguments != null && paragraphsArguments.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphsArguments.Count; i++)
        {
            alias = "p" + i.ToString();
            dc = DetachedCriteria.For<Document>().SetProjection(Projections.Id());
            dc.CreateAlias("paragraphList", alias);
            dc.Add(Restrictions.Eq(alias + ".paragraphSectionTemplate", paragraphsArguments[i].ParagraphTemplate));
            dc.Add(Restrictions.Like(alias + ".content", paragraphsArguments[i].Argument, MatchMode.Anywhere));
            conjunction.Add(Property.ForName("id").In(dc));
        }
    }
    sourceQuery.Add(conjunction);
}
```

Regards,

Mariusz