# NHibernate QueryOver joining to a collection twice

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, queryover

I am writing a query for a sortable grid using this QueryOver:

```
IQueryOver<Order, Order> query = session.QueryOver(() => _OrderAlias); 
query.Left.JoinQueryOver(() => _OrderAlias.Employees, () => _OrderEmployeeAssigneeAlias,
      () => _OrderEmployeeAssigneeAlias.OrderEmployeeType == OrderEmployeeType.Assignee); 
query.Left.JoinQueryOver(() => _OrderAlias.Employees, () => _OrderEmployeeSalespersonAlias, 
      () => _OrderEmployeeSalespersonAlias.OrderEmployeeType == OrderEmployeeType.SalesPerson); 
query.OrderBy(() => _OrderEmployeeSalespersonAlias.LastName).Desc;
```

Conditionally, the query will be built to sort by Assignee, not by 
Salesperson, so this is the reason for the multiple joins to the same 
table.

Running this query produces this exception:

```
NHibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: Employees ---> 
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been 
added. 
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue 
value, Boolean add) 
   at NHibernate.Util.LinkedHashMap`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) 
   at 
NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.CreateAssociationPathCri teriaMap()
```

I have seen posts about doing this with HQL, and a few that say this 
is not currently supported in the Criteria API.

Is this correct?  Is HQL the only way to join to a collection twice?

Can I do this using QueryOver?  (Also, is there a better way to do 
this than using two joins?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello,

i posted my answear in other thread with same problem you can take a look if you have still that problem
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118863/nhibernate-multiple-join-to-the-same-table-by-different-keys/10104467#10104467)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a limitation I have hit before.

I had a similar problem recently and wanted to stick with QueryOver and custom projection with a Transformer. I was able to resolve by doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN, using case..then..else expressions on the outer table and then GROUP BY to coalesce the results back to the desired single row for transformation to a DTO. However, I think this approach is only useful if you are working with DTOs.